# Seforim Recommendations on Bava Metzia

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, bava-metzia

Any recommendations on seforim that deals with (commentaries or insights) Bava Metzia (especially on Perek Eilu Metzios)? Preferably in English. Preferably seforim that explain the deeper meaning of the teachings found there.

Did any of the Chabad Rebbeim write such commentaries? (Thanks to ShimonS for answering this). Or are there any other seforim that are a must read?

Comment: Your anecdote, while interesting, is kind of unnecessary to include

Comment: https://seforimdeals.com/products/tosfos-in-english-bava-metzia?_pos=2&_sid=24d29c247&_ss=r

Comment: not in English, but here are the Tzemach Tzedek's Chiddushim on Shas: https://hebrewbooks.org/16092

Answer (score 2):

1. If Chabad commentary is the priority, there is a Chabad "version" of the Gemara - it contains the regular Oz Vehadar text followed by a compilation of commentaries of the Rebbes. The chief editior is Rabbi Yochanan Gurary (Rav of Holon). Bava Metzia was published in 2012.

http://shturem.net/index.php?section=news&id=57819

2. If English is the priority, your best bet would be Artscroll (3 vols) or Koren Steinsaltz (2 vols).
3. Otherwise, there are great compilations of commentaries, such as Oz Vehadar Mesivta (6 vols), Otzar Mefarshei Hatalmud or Kovetz Mefarshim.

Comment: Thanks. Any English recommendations besides ArtScroll (Already have it) and Tosfos? Like a commentary?

Comment: Something like this (see the sample on Amazon)? https://www.amazon.com/Gemara-Tosfos-Rabbi-Chaim-Smulowitz/dp/1517095921

Comment: There is even a comic book about Eilu Metzios... https://www.amazon.com/Gemarah-Gems-Comics-Eilu-Metzios/dp/1449597017